# What does "slope.lt(5)" do in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, flood

Can someone explain what "***.lt***" is in the code below, and how it works?

```
var hydrosheds = ee.Image('WWF/HydroSHEDS/03VFDEM');
var terrain = ee.Algorithms.Terrain(hydrosheds);
var slope = terrain.select('slope');
var before1 = before.mask(slope.lt(5));
var after1 = after.mask(slope.lt(5);
Map.addLayer(after1, {palette:"red"},'flooded areas - red',1);
```

Comment: lt = less than. So in your example: Mask everything where the slope is more than 5. Also look at the Earth Engine documentation. You will find everything there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lt means LowerThan, so basically you've masked any slope which is higher than 5 (degrees I'm assuming). If you ever have a doubt on what a function does, click on the 'Docs' tab on GEE and type in the name of the function you're unsure about, a short description comes out.

Comment: Thank you so much for your clear explanation

Comment: You are welcome! Could you accept the answer so I may gain points? ^^